# How to change PARTITION in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

version 18.16.1

```
CREATE TABLE traffic (
    `date` Date,
    ...
) ENGINE = MergeTree(date, (end_time), 8192);
```

I want to change as `PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date)` without drop table how to do that.

Answer (score 8):

Since [ALTER query](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql_reference/statements/alter/) does not allow the partition alteration, the possible way is to create a new table

```sql
CREATE TABLE traffic_new
(
    `date` Date,
    ...
)
ENGINE = MergeTree(date, (end_time), 8192)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(date);
```

and to move your data

```sql
INSERT INTO traffic_new SELECT * FROM traffic WHERE column BETWEEN x and xxxx;
```

Rename the final table if necessary.
And yes, this option involves deleting the old table (seems to be no way to skip this step)